# Using selenium java I want to automate a survey page, with 11 questions. Every question has multiple answers

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, testng

My survey page has a first page with "select age" and "select sex". After I select these options, the "Continue" button is displayed, and follow the next page. Every page has a question.

The HTML code is:

```
    <div id="survey-container"><div id="navigation-survey" style="display: none;"><strong>Pas NaN<span> / 11</span></strong><ul><li style="display: none;"><a class="isDisabled">1</a></li><li style="display: none;"><a class="isDisabled">2</a></li><li><a class="isDisabled">3</a></li><li><a class="isDisabled">4</a></li><li><a class="isDisabled">5</a></li><li><a class="isDisabled">6</a></li><li><a class="isDisabled">7</a></li><li><a class="isDisabled">8</a></li><li><a class="isDisabled">9</a></li><li><a class="isDisabled">10</a></li><li><a class="isDisabled">11</a></li><li><a class="isDisabled">12</a></li><li><a class="isDisabled">14</a></li></ul></div> <div class="start-survey-container"><div class="questions columns-2"><div><strong class="title">NaN. Selecteaza varsta</strong> <p class="description" style="display: none;"></p> <div class="question"><strong class="title">Selecteaza varsta</strong> <div class="answers"><label><img class="icon" style="display: none;"> <input type="radio" name="select-1" value="0">    18-30   </label></div><div class="answers"><label><img class="icon" style="display: none;"> <input type="radio" name="select-1" value="1">    31-50   </label></div><div class="answers"><label><img class="icon" style="display: none;"> 
<input type="radio" name="select-1" value="2">    51-70   </label></div><div class="answers"><label><img class="icon" style="display: none;"> <input type="radio" name="select-1" value="3">    71-   </label></div> </div> <div class="disclaimer" style="display: none;"><label><input type="checkbox" id="disclaimer"> Text</p></div> <div classname="clearfix"></div> <div class="actions"><a id="prev" class="btn gray" style="display: none;">   Inapoi  </a> <a id="next" class="btn isDisabled" style="display: none;">   Continua  </a></div></div>
<div><strong class="title">NaN. Selecteaza sex</strong> <p class="description" style="display: none;"></p> <div class="question"><strong class="title">Selecteaza sex</strong> <div class="answers"><label><img class="icon" style="display: none;"> <input type="radio" name="select-2" value="0">    Masculin   </label></div><div class="answers"><label><img class="icon" style="display: none;"> <input type="radio" name="select-2" value="1">    Feminin   </label></div> </div>
```

The problem is that any locator you create does not access the desired item. Maybe is necessary a wait time after every question?

My locator:

```
@FindBy(css = "#survey-container input[type='radio'], input[value='0']")
    WebElement years;

@FindBy(css = "#survey-container > div.start-survey-container > div.questions.columns-2 > div:nth-child(2) > div.question > div:nth-child(3) > label > input[type=radio]")
    WebElement sex;

    @FindBy(css = "#survey-container > div.start-survey-container > div.questions.columns-2 > div:nth-child(1) > div.question > div:nth-child(2) > label")
    WebElement startSurvey;
```

Is there an easier way to identify the desired item? You can suggest to me some tutorials anything related to the automation of a survey page?

If the question is not very clear I am grateful if you would tell me how to write good questions, in accordance with the StackOverflow rules. New shot around here. Thanks!

The questions are like:
[survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CITM5.png)

Comment: Any chance you can share the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can you check with below code, I hope this will help**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//input[@name='select- 
                    1'])[1])"));
WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(((//input[@name='select- 
                    2'])[1])"));
WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='start- 
                    survey']"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
     
     executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);   
     executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element2);
     executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element3);
```

I've used the JavascriptExecutor interface to interact with the element, As earlier, atleast this works, you may enhance it as per your requirement.

- Not followed the @FindBy.

Answer (score 0):

The flow should be like below :

- **select age** - It could be a `drop down` or a `input field`.
- **select sex** - Mostly it would be a `radio` `button`.

Your **locator** :

```
@FindBy(css = "#survey-container > div.start-survey-container > div.questions.columns-2 > div:nth-child(2) > div.question > div:nth-child(3) > label > input[type=radio]")
WebElement sex;
```

I believe it can be written in a more reliable way with CSS [reference here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Is there an easier way to identify the desired item?  - follow the above link

You can suggest to me some tutorials anything related to the automation of a survey page? - I do not think that a tutorial link is something that can be much helpful only regards to Survey page. Though I would suggest you to have a look [XPATH reference](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

Selenium-Java [Official documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/)

As a beginner you may want to have a look [here](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-tutorial/)

Always make use of **ExplicitWait** Something like this :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a/h3")));
```

Comment: Hi, I added an image with the survey, and thank you for the references.

Comment: You need to provide HTML in text format to get more prompt response

Comment: I added an image with all HTML

Comment: Do me a favor, copy the exact same thing in text format and paste here. It would be really difficult for me to write locators outta image.

Comment: The limit of characters does not let me put all the code is very much, I put a part in the description.

Comment: yes and no, I tried with the dev tool but is more code. I tried to write by hand, and I put it in the description.

Comment: Can you share URL ?

Comment: Now, I changed the selector, but again I can' t  select the element when I run the program.

Comment: New selector is @FindBy(css = "#survey-container > div.questions.normal.question-1  .answers label input[value='0']")
    WebElement ages;

Comment: In dev tool, the element is identified with this selector

Comment: I need to see how does it look like in HTML `#survey-container > div.questions.normal.question-1 .answers label input[value='0']`

Comment: In dev tool, the element is identified with this selector  - then what is the error ?

Comment: I don't have an error, when I run the program, the page is opened, but the test is failed because the program doesn't click the button.

Comment: I tried to do a Select age = new Select(driver. find.Element(with the selector)).\

Comment: I tried with WebDriverWait, but I can't do click on the element.

Comment: Either share URL or entire HTML structure in any could platform

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[text() =' 31-50 ']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[text() = ' Masculin ']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[text()='Continue']")).click();
```